# Hangfire with Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, hangfire

I am trying to connect hangfire with Azure Cosmos DB, but I am getting exception 
`MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command renameCollection failed: Command is not supported.'` in `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMongoStorage`.

When I am trying to connect with Azure VM hosted MongoDB, it is working fine.

Comment: Cosmos DB's collections cannot be renamed. So there would be no way to support renames via Cosmos DB's MongoDB API, aside from copying content between collections in the background (which could be both costly and time consuming, depending on the source collection's size). VM-hosted MongoDB, that you referred to, is using a native MongoDB engine, which would provide you with 100% of MongoDB's feature set (but is a separate product from Cosmos DB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im contributing to the Hangfire.Mongo lib you are using. We have changed the migrations to support CosmosDB. So the issue you are experiencing should be solved in the latest release.

We currently do not actively test against CosmosDB as we target MongoDB. But please submit issues you find with CosmosDB to https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/Hangfire.Mongo
I would be happy to accept PR's fixing CosmosDB related issues, or provide the patch myself if time permits.

Comment: When using the Hangfire.Mongo lib for Cosmos DB for Mongo API, we will face 2 problems:
1. Cosmos DB does not support Capped Collections - the Hangfire.Mongo tries to create some Capped collections "hangfire.notifications" and "hangfire.signals"
2. If we try to change the code to create a normal collection for Cosmos DB, we must add a TTL index to simulate the Capped collection.

Comment: Is there a solution for running Hangfire on cosmos db? I am facing a similar issue where we have migrated our bd from vm hosted MongoDB to cosmos MongoDB and the application stopped working. I am getting an error - Unable to create a capped collection. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Hangfire.Mongo v1.7.2, and getting Version 15.createcompositekey error

Answer (score 0):

> 'Command renameCollection failed: Command is not supported.'

The command is not supported by cosmos db mongo api yet.

Per my knowledge, CosmosDB just supports a subset of the MongoDB API and translates requests into the CosmosDB SQL equivalent. CosmosDB has some different behaviours and results. But the onus is on CosmosDB to improve their emulation of MongoDB.

In addition, you could add feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to submit your requirements.Or you could consider using [MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/microsoft-azure/) on Azure if you'd like full MongoDB feature support.

Comment: Telling someone that something is "obvious" is not really helpful. Also: given that Cosmos DB's native collections (containers) cannot be renamed, there would be no way to support this via MongoDB API unless 1) rename became available with native collections or 2) a background collection-to-collection copy were executed, which is impractical and potentially costly and time-consuming.